# Change css whenever scroll is between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I tried to change my `.products` whenever it was between `#trigger-start` and `#trigger-end`, I created this jQuery file but for some reason it doesn't work quite good. The alerts do work whenever I enable them tho.

### jQuery

```
var scrollFilter1 = $('#trigger-start').offset().top;
var scrollFilter2 = $('#trigger-end').offset().top;
var windowPosY = $(this).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(windowPosY >= scrollFilter1 && windowPosY <= scrollFilter2){
        //alert('yey');
        $('.products').css('opacity','0.6');
    } else {
        //alert('ney');
        $('.products').css('opacity','1');
    }
});
```

And yes the 2 divs (trigger-start --end are placed in html and styled in css)

Image to show you what I mean
[image]

### fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhragmd6/2)

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle / codepen ?

Comment: Can you provide a Snippet ? StackOverflow allow it without requiring external site...

Comment: if you say alerts are working then is this `$('.products')` fetching any element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rhragmd6/2/  I hope this works :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add a real demo to show how you can implement your code then change your code to this

```js
var scrollFilter1 = $('#trigger-start').offset().top;
var scrollFilter2 = $('#trigger-end').offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > scrollFilter1 && $w.scrollTop() < scrollFilter2 ) {  
        $('.products').addClass('bluebg');
    } else {
      $('.products').removeClass('bluebg');
    }
});
```

```css
.products{
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.bluebg{
 background:blue;
}
#sth-top{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
    background:black;


}
#trigger-start{
    height:300px;
  width:400px;
     background:purple;
   
}
#sth-middle{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
     background:black;
}

#trigger-end{
    height:300px;
  width:400px;
     background:purple;
}
#sth-bottom{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
    background:black;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products"></div>
<div id="sth-top"></div>
<div id="trigger-start"></div>
<div id="sth-middle"></div>
<div id="trigger-end"></div>
<div id="sth-bottom"></div>
```

hope it works for you; You need to add your custom CSS and Class or whatever you want.

Comment: Cant check atm my host is getting ddossed but the snippet works so I guess I'll get there, thanks for ur help : )

Comment: it's jQuery it would show the same even on your host ! it's actually working on the Browsers not host as it's javascript. Anyway if you think I can help more please let me know

Comment: ye but i had 2 adjust a few things because my file was different than I posted on this site lol : 3 but ye it worked : )